# Call to undefined method DB::escape_string()

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Here is simplified version of my code:

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'database') or die(mysqli_error());    

$gender = $db->escape_string($_GET['gender']);
$city = $db->escape_string($_GET['city']);
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Call to undefined method DB::escape_string() in /blablabla/bla/file.php on line 2
```

Why am I getting an error?

Comment: If you use prepared statements, theres no need for `real_escape_string`

Comment: Yes, I am going to learn how to do prepared statements for this. It would be nice to know what is causing that error though.

Comment: Okay, I had another variable named $db deep inside my files. I feel stupid now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [`mysqli::real_escape_string()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

```
$gender = $db->real_escape_string($_GET['gender']);
$city = $db->real_escape_string($_GET['city']);
```

Comment: Already tried that...
    Call to undefined method DB::real_escape_string().
Aren't they the same thing anyways.

Comment: Nope. MySQLi doesn't have a `escape_string()` method. Plus, in the mysql_* functions they work *very* differently.

Comment: @JohnConde actually i does... http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: `real_escape_string() != escape_string()`

Comment: That still didn't fix the problem though. How is real_escape_string() undefined?

Comment: The documentation disagrees with you

Comment: @nick Show me a link to the `mysqli::escape_string()` function please.

Comment: @Nick, you do realize that's an *alias* of real_escape_string(), right?

Comment: I realize from what i just read that, "MySQLi doesn't have a escape_string()" is incorrect. unless you can explain to me differently.

Comment: Look at the mysql_escape_string() and mysql_real_escape_string functions and compare the two. You'll see exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

`escape_string` is an alias to `real_escape_string`, so they're identical.

here's a link for documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

try this

```
 $city = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['city']);
```